# How to call InvokeRepeating after a keypress in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to call InvokeRepeating() after any key has been pressed...After i press any key I am moving a ball...currently platforms are spawning at the start of the game but I need them to spawn after I press any key...

I tried doing this but obviously it didnt work...

```
void Start () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            InvokeRepeating("SpawnPlatforms", 0.3f, 0.3f);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling this in the `Start()` method which will only be called once at the beginning, where you will probably not yet press the mouse key. Consider copying this code into the `Update()` function of your script.

Comment: I suggest using events as opposed to hardcoding inputs, but other than that @Ian H. is right about needing to move your code to update() as opposed to start().

Comment: If i move the code to Update() or FixedUpdate() then the platforms are created very rapidly and the 0.3 second duration is ignored....

Comment: @falahmahmood in that case you you need to make a check (or set and check a bool) to make sure the InvokeRepeat only happens one time.

Comment: @ryemoss should I write InvokeRepeat() in Update() and in Update() check that InvokeRepeat() only runs once???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
void Update() {
  if (Input.anyKeyDown) {
    if (!IsInvoking("SpawnPlatforms"))
      InvokeRepeating("SpawnPlatforms", 0.3f, 0.3f);
  } else {
     CancelInvoke();
  }
}
```